# Delete elements from database using checkboxes with forms in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a table showing information from a mysql table and in the last column I have a checkbox like this :

```
<form method="POST" action="php/delete.php">
  <thead>
    <tr
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Espéce</th>
      <th>Cri</th>
      <th>Propiétaire</th>
      <th>Age (années)</th>
      <th><input type="submit" name="supprimer" value="Supprimer" /></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $connexion = mysql_connect($hote, $login, $mdp);
      mysql_select_db($bd, $connexion);
      $req = "Select * from animaux;";
      $resultat = mysql_query($req, $connexion);
      while (list($id, $nom, $esp, $cri, $prop, $age) = mysql_fetch_row($resultat)) {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $nom ?> </td>
        <td><?= $esp ?></td>
        <td><?= $cri ?></td>
        <td><?= $prop ?></td>
        <td><?= $age ?></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="choix[]" value=<?= $id ?>></td>
      </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </form>
```

I am using the following script to delete the rows :

```
  include("../BD/bd_params.inc.php");

  $connexion = mysql_connect($hote,$login,$mdp);
  mysql_select_db($bd, $connexion);

  $del = $_POST['choix'];

  foreach ($del as $val) {
    $req = "delete from `animaux` where id = '$val'";
    $resultat = mysql_query($req,$connexion);

    if (!resultat) {
      die('Requête invalide : ' . mysql_error());
      break;
    } 
  }
```

However when i submit the form nothing happens, nothing is shown and nothing is deleted. Does anyone what could be causing my script not working ?

(oh, and sorry for my english ...)

Comment: Looks correct to me. Try turning on errors and see if you get any info.

Comment: at the top of your script add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

Comment: it doesn't print anything... However now i am able to delete only element at time, even if several are selected. And when i'm adding `var_dump($_POST);` when i check several boxes, it shows : `array(2) { ["supprimer"]=> string(9) "Supprimer" ["choix"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" } } `. So apparently, the array 'choir' doesn't work properly...

Comment: Okay, apparently it's only working with the first checkbox checked. Furthermore, in the array, the only value is a string so i have to cast it before making any sql query. Any idea how to have all values in the POST array ?

Comment: if you do a `print_r($_POST)`, what do you see?

Comment: I see `Array ( [supprimer] => Supprimer [choix] => Array ( [5] => 5 ) )`, with two boxes checked.

Comment: OK, what does the html look like that is generated by your php script? You're only getting one value from your choix array, so my guess is something is messed up on the html side.

Comment: [Here's](http://pastebin.com/jUr6S7Vu) the whole form.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the html **generated** by the php. What does the browser output?

Comment: Oh, sorry, [here](http://pastebin.com/mwRAwt5s) you go.

Comment: or did you mean what it looks like? [here](http://cl.ly/BUmO) you go then.

Comment: OK, the problem is your php loops. You have `forms` being open and closed irregularly - therefore, the choix[] checkboxes aren't all being included in the $_POST array. Go back through the php and sure-up those loops.

Comment: You mean like closing the while loop before the form "Mise a jour", and create another loop for this form ?

Comment: No, see my answer below. In your current pastebin, you open the form before the `tbody`, then you close the form **within** your loop - which means you have 1 `<form>` and **many** `</form>` - so the document thinks the `id="del"` form is closed **after** the first checkbox. However, the intent is that the form isn't closed until **after** the loop completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new version of your pastebin here:

http://pastebin.com/KdqscV87

Basically, you want to open the form before you start the loop and close the form after you finish the loop.

I've removed the hidden (`class="invisible"`) form (you can't have a form within a form) from the loop. I'm not sure what you're needing there, but it won't work inside the other form.

Comment: Thank you this is working ! (the hidden `class="invisible"` actually appears when the `<th>nom</th>` is clicked. it makes disappear the first form and appear this one thanks to javascript.)

Comment: OH, ok. I'd say to create that form after the loop and then manipulate it with javascript to show it where you need it with the correct ids, etc. when you click on that th. That way, you don't have multiple forms, just one that you can change based on the th that was clicked.

Comment: You mean like using a javascript function that have the id of the th clicked, and thanks to this displaying the corresponding values in the other form ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!resultat) {
```

should be

```
if (!$resultat) {
     ^--missing $
```

The 'break' call is superfluous. die() will kill the script, so it'll be impossible for the break to be reached.

Have you verified that there is something being sent to the server. What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` shows `array(2) { ["supprimer"]=> string(9) "Supprimer" ["choix"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } }`.  I guess i have to cast the strings into integers ?

Comment: OK. So a checkbox is being sent. So... Add some debugging output: `var_dump($req); var_dump($resultat)`, etc... and see what comes out.

Comment: `var_dump($req)` : `string(36) "delete from animaux where id = '1'"` var_dump($resultat)` : `bool(true)`

Comment: According to that, the db operation worked. You'll have to check why it's not actually deleting anything.

Comment: It's working now, but only if `id` < 5 and if only one checkbox is checked.

Comment: Okay, apparently it's only working with the first checkbox checked. Furthermore, in the array, the only value is a string so i have to cast it before making any sql query. Any idea how to have all values in the POST array ?